# Finding specific array or list in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a list of numpy arrays, which consists of all possible configurations of 0 and 1 in a 10-pixel arrays. I'm trying to determine the number of arrays that have specific group of 1s for more than two 1s. For example, the array is [1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1]. I want to determine this array has five 1s as a block. Another example, the array is [1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1]. I want to find the block as six 1s instead of three 1s block. I couldn't find a way to do this.

Here is the code I generate the list of all possible arrays:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import product

all_arrays = np.array(list(product([0,1], repeat=10)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert the array to a string and check for membership along the lines of:

```
str_array = ''.join(my_array)
return 5*'1' in str_array
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below approach.
Its not very efficient, but it should work.

```
from functools import reduce
import numpy as np
from itertools import product

n=int(input("How many 1s you want?"))
all_arrays = list(filter(lambda x : n*"1" in x and (n+1)*"1" not in x,map(lambda e : reduce(lambda x,y : str(x)+str(y), e), product([0,1], repeat=10))))
print(len(all_arrays))
```

Comment: I was trying to determine this number of 1-blocks for each of the array, instead of generating with a specific number of 1s-block. The solution above worked for this. Thank you for your code though, I can use it for something else!

Comment: So, just to clarify. You want the count but you are trying to avoid generating the arrays, right?

Comment: Yes, that is right. I'm trying to count the number of 1s in a group of 1s for each array in the list